# Not allowing to rename a datagridview Column

Tags: vb.net

Hi i am Naming a Datagridview Column as "Class" it is giving me a message 
"'Class' is not a valid identifier"
Can anybody help me?

Comment: @Steve it is a Column of a datagridView and i want to give a name there is no code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can call your column "Class" in VB.Net since it's a keyword.  Name it almost anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically, just not in the form designer:

```
    Dim dg As New DataGridView
    dg.Columns.Add("Class", "ClassHeader")
```

Comment: +1 Very true actually.  Still probably isn't a good idea to name it that though.